# Working out due date

Tags: pregnancy-birth

I remember hearing once that there is a gematria how to work out the due date, something like the gematria of Ibur either 282 (w/o the vav) or 288 (with vav) from the last leil tevila. It may have been another similar word.
Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Bit long either way (term is defined medically as 273-280 days)

Comment: It may have been different amount....

Comment: @AKA but the medical definition you are using counts from last period, as opposed to the OP who specified from last leil tevila (around 12 days after the period)

Comment: So all the more so it's wrong, as the medical equivalent should then be 268 days